# Rstudio - Markdown not adding data to Global Environment anymore

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

My markdown script use to work perfectly. But suddenly, it's not adding new data (variables or dataframes) into the the Rstudio Global Enviroment.

This is how I set the R script:

[image]

The script runs just fine, but it's not included in the Global Environment, that means if I want to call the the variable / data frame later it doesn't exist in the environment:

[image]

Comment: If you do not knit (render) your document, but run the selected chunks individually, it should load the objects again in your environment.

Comment: Thanks @Julian that's amazing, I didn't know I can also run selected lines in markdown as regular R scrips individually.
I did it and works, now I have the variable in the Environment, that is great. But do you know why when I run the full markdown it has a different behaviour.  
At least you solve my problem! thanks!